# EEA family permit eligibility for the UK

Tags: visas

I am a German citizen. My wife is a Pakistani passport holder with a German normal visa which is in her passport.  We have been married since 2015. I would like to travel to the UK with my wife for a week. We have lived together in Germany since 2016. I would like to know if she can apply for a EEA family permit to travel to the UK with me.  If so, which documents does she need in order to apply?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit? If you have a specific problem you need help with after reading the information, you can edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes i have looked at gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit. but can not understand is in my case thes think. I am very unsure.

Comment: That page says exactly which documents you need. What do you still have a question about?

Comment: and what kind of proof of your dependency if you’re dependent on your EEA family member shell i show i mean have i to write a letter or what.

Answer (score 2):

To qualify for an EEA family permit, certain relationships require dependency.  In particular, parents and adult children fall under the directive's definition of "family member" only of they are dependant on the EEA national.

This criterion does not apply to spouses (nor to underage children).  You can therefore ignore it in your spouse's application.

Comment: Thank yor your replay.  That means we need to Submit with Application these Documents:  my German Passport, My wife Passport with visa,  Our Marriage Certificat. Thats it. Right?

Comment: @WaqasNaeem yes, I believe so.

Comment: I have Last Think. My Father In Low ( My Wife Father Biritish Citizen) send for my Wife a Sponser Letter. In The Letter is only her Name shell i also Submit the Sponser Letter? Thank You for Your Help.

Comment: @WaqasNaeem you can include a letter, but it should not be necessary unless you need to explain any relevant facts that are not otherwise apparent from the other documents.

Comment: Thank you for ur Replay. I have Complett my Application in my Checklist at page 4 they as for About or visit flight Booking. And they are asking for Money ( Incoming or Saving? Have i to Submit Bankstaments?

Comment: @WaqasNaeem In my experience, the application asks for many things that it should't be asking for.  But I do not remember whether bank statements were among them; do double check that you are using the correct application for an EEA family permit.  If it does in fact ask, you can answer "not applicable," but that probably increases the likelihood of an improper refusal.  We answered all the questions they asked even when they were improper.  But if they don't explicitly ask for bank statements, which they should not, I would not include them.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for ur replay. The Visa Typ is European Family Permit.

Comment: Hello together,
i have Appled for my Wife EEA Family Permit. She has Submittes Application online on 10.02.2020 and we Made Apointment on 05.03.2020 to düsseldorf Germany for Biomstric Information and Documents. On 10.03.2020 We Resived email that our Application as recived by Decison Making Center. On 20.03.2020 We recived Email saying that Your Application was not Straightforward They will tell us wenn the Desicion has been Made. On 26.03.2020 i called the Visa Hotline and they have done escalation on Wife Application. Till now we didnt got any Answar from they.
Best regards
Waqas